# mysql max length on columns and ensuring I don't go over that limit using utf8_unicode_ci - PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, string, text, unicode

I am using a `TEXT` column which is `ut8_unicode_ci` in mysql to store some data that is scraped from over the internet.

The texts that are gathered are from various sites in different languages.

I am getting confused with the max length of `65535` bytes for a `TEXT` column.

How can I check that the strings I am inserting into the column do not go over that limit?

At the minute I am using `strlen($str)` to check the length of the strings, but by using this does it make sure it that the data will not be truncated to fit into the column as I understand `utf8_unicode_ci` can be more than 1 byte per character?

Comment: ¿Did you try using mb_strlen()? http://php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strlen.php

Comment: Yes but in all cases where `mb_strlen($str) != strlen($str)` the actual result from `strlen` is more of that from `mb_strlen`, and the result from `mb_strlen` counts multi byte characters as 1

Comment: It's not a solution, but you could move out with MEDIUMTEXT (16777215 chars) or LONGTEXT (4294967295 chars) if you are running out of space with just TEXT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** The OP can simply use `strlen()` as it returns bytes, not characters. Witness:

```
$ cat test.php
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
echo strlen("דותן כהן")."\n";
echo mb_strlen("דותן כהן", "UTF-8")."\n";
?>

$ ./test.php 
15
8
```

Credit goes to [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) in a comment to this post.

**Old post below:**

The notes of the PHP manual have [a handy function for determining how many bytes are in a string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php#72274). It seems to be the only alternative to using [MYSQL built in functions such as `LENGTH` to do the job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11011360/343302), which would be cumbersome here.

There are two other possible workarounds. Firstly, you can write the string to a file and check the file's size. Secondly, you can force the ASCII encoding on mb_strlen and then it will treat each byte as a character, so the amount of characters that it returns is actually the amount of bytes. I haven't tested this, so check it first. Let us know what works for you!

Comment: What you actually need to do is use [`strlen`](http://php.net/strlen), period. Writing the string to a file and checking its size is the same as using `strlen`, which is simply counting bytes.

Comment: `strlen` does count bytes. It's one of the naive PHP core functions that assumes that one byte equals one character. `strlen('漢')` returns `3`, because it counts bytes, while `mb_strlen('漢', 'UTF-8')` correctly counts characters and returns `1`.

Comment: @deceze: You are correct. I just tested with `strlen("דותן כהן")` and `mb_strlen("דותן כהן", "UTF-8")`. The former prints 15 while the latter prints 8. Thank you very much!

Comment: @deceze I wish the docs would be more clear about this! Thanks :) this has helped me and made my life simpler alot :)

Comment: It turns out that there is [a bug in the PHP docs to fix this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45676).

Comment: @hadley Glad it helped, but I don't know this actually answers your question. MySQL's utf8 variant doesn't use the same amount of bytes as regular UTF-8, if I remember correctly. You'll have to test whether this actually gives you the correct information in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout MySQL function LENGTH() :

> Returns the length of the string str, measured in bytes. A multi-byte
>   character counts as multiple bytes. This means that for a string
>   containing five two-byte characters, LENGTH() returns 10, whereas
>   CHAR_LENGTH() returns 5.